# Open secure Sharepoint file programmatically using c#

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, dialog, httpresponse, user-permissions

I need help opening am online Sharepoint file programmatically. These files need to be secured on Sharepoint (so that users can't wander into them), but I also need to access it somehow using my webpart (which will check for security). Normally, you can just use a hyperlink that links to the Sharepoint file, but we don't want people sharing these hyperlinks, so that won't work.

I want the user to click a link, and have them see the "Open, Save, Close" dialog menu for that file.

I have tried this

```
            String fileName = @"file.txt";
            String filePath = @"~online filePath/"; 

            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
            //or whatever file type, I can code that later
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=" + fileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(filePath + fileName);
            //response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Unfortunately, while this works fine for local files (C://...), when I try this on my web fike, I only receive a text document that has the source code for the current page. Not sure why.

As for dealing with the permissions, I plan to use elevated priviledges to have the program gain access to the files.

I would appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code to provide a file for download with SharePoint

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
{
    //Get fileName and filePath here
    response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    SPFile file = web.GetFile(filePath);
    byte[] fileBytes = file.OpenBinary();
    response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    response.End();
}
```

Does this help or are you having problems locating the fileName and filePath?

Comment: Thank you! I was having a lot of troubling finding the right way to transmit the files. This is way to get the files. (I use a using clause to impersonate an admin to get the access I want).